# Floating Action Button Plus Sign Not Showing

Tags: java, android, xml, floating-action-button

I have successfully created a FAB with a plus sign in a previous fragment. However, I am trying to create it again and for some reason the emulator is not rendering the plus sign. Here is my XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/add_answers_button"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/actionRed"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
            app:elevation="0dp" />
```

Preview (API 21):

[image]

Emulator:

[image]

And here are the drawables:

[image]

Comment: api version of emulator ??

Comment: 18, I don't think it has to do with the API I've already isolated that aspect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using vector drawables. They are available only started from Lolipop. So you need to include **.png** drawables into your project.

Comment: I have updated to show the drawables I am using, I believe I am using regular.png so I don't really see the issue with that, but thanks for pointing out.